# Render isn't showing my active viewport - just a texture

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

This is only occurring with this one .blend file I'm working on. For some reason rendering the image using Blender Render doesn't give me a fully-rendered version of what I've got in the active camera. Instead it results in a single, flat picture of a texture while OpenGL rendering is giving me the expected result.

[image: Normal render result vs. OpenGL render result]

Any ideas on what settings might be causing this?

.blend file can be downloaded here:
[dof-test.blend](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34318743/dof_test.blend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is broken with the texture definition of "mike_ironfist_advance_sprite_idle_512h". I don't know exactly what because I created new texture identical to the existing, it renders the material and texture preview fine and works in actual render unlike the existing texture.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be the solution that still allows the viewport preview to appear correctly! I just did what you did (added another texture using the same image as the original) and it worked without issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Face Textures and Face Textures Alpha

[image]

And uncheck color as influence

[image]

Comment: Great! That did indeed make the texture show. I don't know what broke the texture in the first place but this definitely fixed it. Thanks for the help!